# Error when trying to declare tappedItem

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to make the user able to check some items on the table view, I actually figured out how but I'm having an error:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:



    NSIndexPath!) {



        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)



      #  var tappedItem: AssesmentsManager = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row] as



        AssesmentsManager


      #  tappedItem.send = !tappedItem.send



        tableView.reloadData()



}
```

It says that *task is not convertible to AssesmentMAnager*
 and *AssesmentManager doesn't have a member called completed*.

Here is the class *AssesmentManager.swift*:

```
import UIKit

var taskMgr : AssesmentsManager = AssesmentsManager()

struct task {
    var name = "Un-Named"
    var score = "No-Score"
    var send = false
}

class AssesmentsManager: NSObject {

    var tasks = [task]()

    func addtask(name: String, score: String, send: Bool) {

        tasks.append(task(name: name, score: score, send: send))

    }


}
```

Comment: And the compiler is once again correct - task is in fact not convertible to AssesmentsManager (how should that conversion / cast look like?). And neither the task nor the AssesmentsManager contain a member completed!

Comment: Would casting it be the right solution?

Comment: no, because they are two completely unrelated types

Comment: what can i do to fix this? i need to declare tappedItem so that when the user taps it a checkmark appears on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add completed as a bool variable to your task struct

```
struct task {
    var name = "Un-Named"
    var score = "No-Score"
    var send = false
}
class AssesmentsManager: NSObject {

    var tasks = [task]()

    func addtask(name: String, score: String, send : Bool) {

        tasks.append(task(name: name, score: score, send: send))

    }
}
```

Try just to edit the value directly

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath!) {

     tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)

     taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].send = !taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: I added it but it still give me the same error that this member doesn't exist in AssesmentManager

Comment: in "if let task = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row] {" it gives me the error bound value in a conditional binding must be optional type

Comment: if let task = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row] as? task{

Comment: it's working now after making it only a one line statement instead of declaring a variable tappedItem

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that there is no such `method or function or property` of the name **completed** . Therefore in the class **AssesmentsManager** you will need to implement one

Comment: it's fixed now after adding completed, but it still says task is not convertible to AssesmentManager

Comment: can you update your code and show which line it crashes

Comment: I updated it, the lines that beging with # are the ones that give me error

Comment: `var tappedItem = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row] as!
        AssesmentsManager` try that

Comment: it says "Cast from *task* to unrelated type *AssesmentsManager* always fails"

Comment: try replacing as!  with as?

Comment: after I did it says task is not convertible to AssesmentManager

Comment: the error is gone but, when I run the app no checkmark appears next to the tapped items  :/